# Excel VBA Scrape amazon for inventory

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am seeking for scraping amazon inventory .. Here's the link I used 
[https://www.amazon.com/Stratford-Pharmaceuticals-Omega-Fatty-Strength/dp/B006JCU54Y/ref=sr_1_2?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1518816130&sr=1-2&keywords=stratford](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006JCU54Y)

There is a part with the title "Compare with similar items" in which I need to extract prices (I have already done that) and also the inventory quantity ..
The second part is not directly obtained .. Manually I have to cick "Add to Cart" then from the next page click "Cart" then from the next page select "Quantity drop down and select 10+ and manually type any large number say 999 and click "Update"
There will be alert message that contains the remaining in inventory like that
(This seller has only 35 of these available. To see if more are available from another seller,) >> so this is the desired number which is 35
Here's the excel file and snapshots that illustrates the manual steps .. 
I used IE but if it is possible to use XMLHTTP it would be great of course

Here's the code I devised till now

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ie          As Object
    Dim allLnks     As Object
    Dim lnk         As Object
    Dim r           As Long
    Dim liElem As Object
    Dim prElem As Object
    Dim crtElem As Object
    Dim elem As Object
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim inputElem As Object
    Dim inputEle As Object
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("https://www.amazon.com/Stratford-Pharmaceuticals-Omega-Fatty-Strength/dp/B006JCU54Y/ref=sr_1_2?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1518816130&sr=1-2&keywords=stratford")

        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readystate = 4
        
        ws.Range("B2").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:mm:ss")
        Set liElem = .document.getelementbyid("detail-bullets").getelementsbytagname("table")(0).getelementsbytagname("ul")(0)
        
        For Each elem In liElem.getelementsbytagname("li")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "ASIN") > 0 Then ws.Range("B1").Value = Replace(elem.innerText, "ASIN: ", "")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "Rank:") > 0 Then ws.Range("B3").Value = MyUDF(elem.innerText, "Rank: ", "(")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "Review:") > 0 Then ws.Range("B4").Value = Replace(Split(Trim(Split(elem.innerText, "Review: ")(1)), vbLf)(1), Chr(13), "")
        Next elem
        
        Set prElem = .document.getelementbyid("comparison_price_row")
        For Each elem In prElem.getelementsbytagname("td")
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ws.Range("A" & cnt + 4).Value = "Seller " & cnt
            ws.Range("B" & cnt + 4).Value = elem.getElementsByClassName("a-offscreen")(0).innerText
        Next elem
        
        cnt = 0
        Set crtElem = .document.getelementbyid("HLCXComparisonTable").getElementsByClassName("a-button-inner")
        For Each elem In crtElem
            .navigate elem.getelementsbytagname("a")(0).href
            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readystate = 4
            .navigate .document.getElementsByClassName("a-button-inner")(0).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).href
            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readystate = 4
            
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ws.Range("C" & cnt + 4).Value = Replace(Split(Split(MyUDF(.document.getElementsByClassName("a-row a-spacing-base sc-action-quantity sc-action-quantity-right")(0).innerHTML, "maxlength=", "quantity="), "autocomplete")(0), "=")(1), """", "")
        Next elem
        
        Stop
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub

Function MyUDF(s As String, b As String, a As String) As String
    Dim arr()       As String
    Dim r           As String

    arr = Split(s, b)

    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        r = arr(1)
        arr = Split(r, a)

        If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
            r = arr(0)
        End If
    End If

    MyUDF = Trim(r)
End Function
```

### Here are snapshots that may help

[image: Prices]

[image: Click Cart]

[image: Enter 999 in quantity[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez7Kt.png)

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Selector to get stock info**

Taking the following example from your code:

[image: Web page]

You can use a CSS selector to target the text regarding stock levels.

```
.sc-product-availability
```

---

**CSS query example using cart view page (generated by your code):**

E.g. CSS query for associated [cart view](https://www.amazon.com/gp/cart/view.html/ref=lh_cart_dup) html

[image: CSS query]

The `.` is the selector for ClassName.

---

**VBA**

You can use the `.document.querySelectorAll` method to retrieve a nodeList of the matching items (2 in the example)

```
Dim nodeList As Object
Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".sc-product-availability")
```

You would then loop over its length to retrieve items (not tested, but this is general method).

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 to nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).innerText
Next i
```

Hopefully that is useful to you.

Comment: Could not find my post useful so get rid of it. However, selenium can be a good option here as it has a built-in facility for explicit wait.

Comment: You think waits are a problem? TBH I did a lot of web questions today so rather than attempt everything shown I attempted to help with solving the sticking point. With more energy tomorrow I might have a look. If you haven't by then.

Comment: I could have handled that by defining explicit wait in IE but that doesn't worth the effort that is why I like to switch to selenium in such case. Wait is definitely a problem here because if you try my script few times then you may get `object variable` error somewhere within it's operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try. It should fetch you the number you are after. I used `xmlhttp` and `Selenium` combinedly to make the script run a little faster. I could not use `xmlhttp` request in my second approach as the link were javascript encrypted.

Upon running the below script you can find out how many of these items the seller has. Even if the seller has no such items, the script will not break as I've already managed that.

There it is:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const base As String = "https://www.amazon.com"
    Const mainurl As String = "https://www.amazon.com/Stratford-Pharmaceuticals-Omega-Fatty-Strength/dp/B006JCU54Y/ref=sr_1_2?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1518816130&sr=1-2&keywords=stratford"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument, itext As Object
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, idic As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim post As Object, oinput As Object, posts As Object, elem As Object
    Dim idrop As Object, oclick As Object, I&, key As Variant

    With Http
        .Open "GET", mainurl, False
        .send
        Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("[id^='comparison_add_to_cart_'].a-button-text")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            idic(base & Replace(.item(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:", "")) = 1
        Next I
    End With

    For Each key In idic.keys
        driver.get key
        Set post = driver.FindElementByCss("input[value='addToCart']", Raise:=False, timeout:=10000)
        If Not post Is Nothing Then
            post.Click
        End If

        Set posts = driver.FindElementById("hlb-view-cart-announce", timeout:=10000)
        posts.Click

        Set elem = driver.FindElementByCss("span#a-autoid-0-announce", timeout:=10000)
        elem.Click

        Set idrop = driver.FindElementById("dropdown1_9", timeout:=10000)
        idrop.Click

        Set oinput = driver.FindElementByCss("input[name='quantityBox']", timeout:=10000)
        oinput.SendKeys "100"

        Set oclick = driver.FindElementByCss("#a-autoid-1", timeout:=10000)
        oclick.Click

        Set itext = driver.FindElementByCss(".sc-quantity-update-message span.a-size-base", Raise:=False, timeout:=5000)
        If Not itext Is Nothing Then
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = itext.Text
        Else
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = "Sorry dear nothing found"
        End If
    Next key
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Selenium Type Library
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

Output you may get like below. Now, you can use regex to parse the number 48:

```
This seller has only 48 of these available. To see if more are available from another seller, go to the product detail page.
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind word @QHarr. The thing is it's not a successful attempt. It can lead us very close, though. Amazon doesn't like bots that is why the script sometimes break before the job is done.

Comment: xml and selenium! I shall have a look at this tomorrow with a fresh head to do it justice:-)

Comment: "Sorry dear nothing found" Lol